# Avalonia UI: Image in DataGrid not displaying

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am an experienced developer but new to the Avalonia UI framework.

I am trying to display to an image in a column within a DataGrid, but nothing is displayed.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Here is the XAML of the column.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

With regards to the binding on the `Image` property I have tried this as an `ImageSource` and a `Bitmap` but neither work. The code for converting the streams to those format is below.

```
public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this Stream image, ImageFormat format = null)
{
    if (format == null)
        format = ImageFormat.Bmp;

    image.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return new Bitmap(image);
}

public static ImageSource ToImageSource(this Stream image, ImageFormat format = null)
{
    if (format == null)
        format = ImageFormat.Png;

    image.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var wpfImage = new BitmapImage();
    wpfImage.BeginInit();
    wpfImage.StreamSource = image;
    wpfImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    wpfImage.EndInit();

    return wpfImage;
}
```

I don't believe there is anything wrong with what I am doing as I can display the image in a window on its own with just an image, I believe the issue is either with my understanding of Avalonia, or the framework itself.